# Is there a way to have a C or C++ program open a new terminal window and start executing code for you?

Tags: c++, c, automation

I want to create a C or C++ program that automates some things for me.

The idea is as such: I run the program `./a.out` and sit back and watch as it opens up three or four new terminal windows and runs various UNIX commands. Is there a way to do this?

I am on a MacBook.

Comment: Why not a shell script?

Comment: Do you actually need "new terminal windows" or are you actually just wanting to run various commands via the program?

Comment: @kaylum there is a specific reason as to why i wanted to have it open new terminal windows -- also, it looks a lot cooler.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274) In general, if you have seen one program that does what you want (such as an installer), then it is possible to do it with a C program and to do it with a C++ program. (They are "general purpose" languages after all.) Not an interesting question.

Comment: If you have good reasons to use C for that (rather than a shell script) you can have a look at `posix_spawn(...)` to create a new terminal process and run your command. If offers better control than `system(...)` over the created process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments point out, this is probably best accomplished by a shell script.  However, you can execute shell commands from C with the [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) standard library function.  To open a terminal, just run a terminal with a particular command.  For example:

```
system("xterm -e 'echo hello; sleep 5'");
```